# Javascript need website URLS shortening down

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am fetching all the websites links and putting them into a array where I will eventually compare them with a JSON list. I need the websites to be shortened down to

Examples (What I'm trying to get the array to look like)

- google.com
- computers.intercom-clicks.com
- mad-websites.ru
- just-eat.com

Example links

- https://mad-websites.ru/via/e?ob=RohpF3uuLGksOJfxJOwcgRL5vknYi4kC2aQRzvu2v3s%3D&h=04ce1caed8c7cf4b69d751230eaf7a2450660d67-o26qxr01_77963700909352&l=6ef96bea4775c44a5bc10cdaa661c5053819c0b8-7456283
- https://notifications.google.com/g/p/AD-FnEwlAH83isfsH0zLOoNuynSmz1pMuK9Y8guqew5CkdyaEu28Zu30iRcw-SI6y7LRO7v8Tqy6p_9LhGcQClO1e2P5WYSVNa9dWPVhmA
- https://finance.rambler.ru/?utm_source=head&utm_campaign=self_promo&utm_medium=topline&utm_content=finance_media
- https://www.google.com/covid19?utm_source=Google-Maps-timeline&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=COVID-site-promo

My code currently only shortens some websites down while others are still the same. It will also remove any duplicates.

```
  const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".a3s a")).map(link => {
      const url = new URL(link.href);
      url.search = '';
      return url.toString(); 
     
  })
  //removes duplicate links
  const uniq = [...new Set(links)];
  //window.alert(uniq);
  return warningPopup(uniq);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

```js
const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".a3s a")).map(link => {
  const url = new URL(link.href);
  return url.hostname;
})

//removes duplicate links
const uniq = [...new Set(links)];

document.write(uniq.join(', '))
```

```html
<div class="a3s">
  <a href="https://mad-websites.ru/via/e?ob=RohpF3uuLGksOJfxJOwcgRL5vknYi4kC2aQRzvu2v3s%3D&h=04ce1caed8c7cf4b69d751230eaf7a2450660d67-o26qxr01_77963700909352&l=6ef96bea4775c44a5bc10cdaa661c5053819c0b8-7456283"></a>
  <a href="https://notifications.google.com/g/p/AD-FnEwlAH83isfsH0zLOoNuynSmz1pMuK9Y8guqew5CkdyaEu28Zu30iRcw-SI6y7LRO7v8Tqy6p_9LhGcQClO1e2P5WYSVNa9dWPVhmA"></a>
  <a href="https://finance.rambler.ru/?utm_source=head&utm_campaign=self_promo&utm_medium=topline&utm_content=finance_media"></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/covid19?utm_source=Google-Maps-timeline&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=COVID-site-promo"></a>
</div>
```